# Batch update XML Sitemap for content type using VBO - D7

Tags: 7, views, xml-sitemap

I am trying to update a portion of my Basic Pages' XML Sitemap setting. By default my Basic Pages are Excluded in the XML Sitemap (what I want), but I want to bulk update only **some** of them (long story). I can manually go to each of the pages and update them to be Included, but that will be a pain.

I tried to use VBO and I created the filters I want, but there isn't a XML Sitemap update Operation. I can create a Rules Action, but again, I couldn't find integration with the XML Sitemap setting.

Is there a setting for bulk updating the XML Sitemap setting that I'm missing? Or some module that does this already?

Other ideas I have if this functionality doesn't exist:

- VBO: Execute arbitrary PHP script & run a Database update
- Rules Action: Create a custom action to run a Database update
- ???

Drupal 7.34, Rules 7.x-2.7, VBO 7.x-3.2, XML Sitemap 7.x-2.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try XML sitemap VBO https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap_vbo It create xml-operations in Bulk operations of views.
[image]

Comment: **chuckle** thanks for reminding me to update my question. This is the solution if someone else runs into this problem.

I created the XMLSiteMap VBO module since there wasn't any other solutions I could find.

Answer (score 0):

[Looks like there isn't really a rules integration yet](https://www.drupal.org/node/439368).  The *best* outcome here would be to write that integration and contribute it to the project.

Failing that, a custom action using PHP would do the trick.  Obviously you should take a backup before executing anything like that.

Comment: Thanks Darvanen for looking at this. I was hoping someone had already created a module for this. Looks like I need to do some work...

Comment: So Darvanen. If you can help me out, please check out my sandbox project - xmlsitemap_vbo - https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/nmillin/2445195. It adds the integration between vbo & xmlsitemap for updating Nodes.

I'll submit an issue with the xmlsitemap project to add this functionality so I don't need to maintain the module, but I wanted to create a sandbox for them to see something that works (hopefully I did it correctly).

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2445217 of the xmlsitemap issue.

Comment: Awesome, I'll take a look as soon as I can.